# How to change the name of file by which it is stored

Tags: php, image-processing

I am using image upload and resize script from someones blog. It stores the name of file as `resize.jpg` .however i want to give unique names to them as data will go in database...I am very bad in using functions so please guide me.

```
 <?php
    class SimpleImage {

     var $image;
     var $image_type;

     function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
            function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75,     $permissions=null) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {

         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image);
      }
    }
       function getWidth() {

      return imagesx($this->image);
      }
      function getHeight() {

      return imagesy($this->image);
      }
       function resizeToHeight($height) {

      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }      

}
?>  
<?php
   if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
      include('SimpleImage.php');
      $image = new SimpleImage();
      $image->load($_FILES['uploaded_image']['tmp_name']);
      $image->resizeToWidth(300);
      $image->resizeToHeight(200);
      $image->save('images/resize.jpg');
      //$image->output();
   } else {
?>   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="uploaded_image" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
   </form><?php
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside this block, you are saving every one as `resize.jpg`

```
  $image->resizeToWidth(300);
  $image->resizeToHeight(200);
  $image->save('images/resize.jpg');
```

You can generate a unique name with [`uniqid()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.uniqid.php) and optionally add a prefix onto it like `img_`.  Your filenames will then look like:

```
'img_4e297753130db.jpg'
```

Start by generating a filename, saved in a variable.

```
$prefix = "img_"
$new_filename = uniqid($prefix) . ".jpg";

// Do your other processing
// ...
$image->resizeToWidth(300);
$image->resizeToHeight(200);

// Save with the new filename
// Note change to double quotes from single...
$image->save("images/$new_filename");
```

Later, when you're ready to store the filename in the database, it's still available in `$new_filename`

Answer (score 0):

The image name is set in this line:

```
$image->save('images/resize.jpg');
```

You will need to determine how you want to name the output files, and modify that line to produce the desired output.

If you can provide more specific detail regarding your statement "i want to give unique names," please update your question.